# 'on square' = near square?

Tags: prepositions

sentence:

> The store is on the square

question:

> Does it sometimes mean that the store **near the square** (not **on the square**)[image]

Comment: Max, that was not a sentence. It will be difficult to know the meaning unless we know what your example means. To 'square' something is different from being on the square.

Comment: You're missing a "the" in the sentence "on **the** square".   But yes, a store can be "on" the square even if it's very *near* the square.  Also "the square" doesn't have to be a perfect square.  Just square-ish.

Comment: If you are talking about a particular square, you probably need a definite article "the store is on **the** square"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Square is used in several ways.  If it refers to a building, like in cobaltduck's answer, "in" is appropriate.  The picture in the question is different.  There, the square doesn't refer to the building.  It refers to [*an open place or area formed at the meeting of two or more streets.* - M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square)

In the picture, this one is perhaps more of a cul-de-sac.  Sometimes the definition is stretched to call an area a "square" even if it is not immediately adjacent to any streets, more of an open people space.  That is the concept of a town square, which is [*an open public space commonly found in the heart of a traditional town used for community gatherings.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_square)

So "in" wouldn't apply there, but "on" also appears wrong, if taken literally.  In this case, though, "on" means bordering.

Urban layouts are planned.  The square isn't just a random open space where some streets happen to meet, it is a design feature of a larger area.  If it has buildings bordering it and opening onto it, the buildings are part of the design.  (Those specific buildings might not have been specified in the original urban design, but the concept of buildings around the square likely was.)  So conceptually, the "square" includes the bordering buildings and in that sense, they are even more literally "on" the square.

Answer (score 0):

In my most familiar usage, I use *in* instead of *on.*  Further, the use is strict, *in* and *near* are not exchangeable.

As an example, here is a snip from the Google map for a *square* not far from where I live and work, called Mulberry Square.

[image]

Unfortunately, at this reduced size, the labels are illegible.  Mulberry Square is those building clustered around the large parking area in the center of the image.  This includes a grocery store, fitness center, a bank, and two or three restaurants.  It would be appropriate to say that each of these is located "in Mulberry Square."

On the other hand, the duplex houses on the right edge of the image, and the additional businesses across the main road to the left, are all *near* Mulberry Square, but not *in* it.